# How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure?

Tags: command-line, osx, curl, ssl

I'm trying to curl HTTPS website in the following way:

```
$ curl -v https://thepiratebay.se/
```

However it fails with the error:

```
* About to connect() to thepiratebay.se port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.245.61.146...
* connected
* Connected to thepiratebay.se (173.245.61.146) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Using `-k`/`--insecure` or adding `insecure` to my `~/.curlrc` doesn't make any difference.

**How do I ignore or force the certificate using `curl` command line?**

---

When using `wget` seems to work fine. Also works when testing with `openssl` as below:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect thepiratebay.se:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL handshake has read 2651 bytes and written 456 bytes
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
```

---

I've:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.28.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0) libcurl/7.28.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8| zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.17
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some sites disable support for SSL 3.0 (possible because of many exploits/vulnerabilities), so it's possible to force specific SSL version by either `-2`/`--sslv2` or `-3`/`--sslv3`.
Also `-L` is worth a try if requested page has moved to a different location.

In my case it was a `curl` bug ([found in OpenSSL](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/861137)), so `curl` needed to be upgraded to the latest version (>7.40) and it worked fine.

See also:

- [3 Common Causes of Unknown SSL Protocol Errors with cURL](http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html)
- [Error when Installing Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679961/error-when-installing-meteor-in-ubuntu) at SO
- [[Bug 861137] Re: Openssl TLS errors while connecting to SSLv3 sites](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2013-July/155861.html)

Comment: Yes, upgrading curl fixed the problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: The latest curl dislikes outdated RC4 cipher that old servers might still use, so I ended up using "--ciphers RC4" to specifically permit it

Comment: @SimonEast From which version to which version did you ugprade?

Comment: Using curl 7.81.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, trying to get a file from https://downloads.leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/ and it does _not_ work. :--(

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Mavericks, Apple switched the TLS/SSL engine from OpenSSL to their own Secure Transport engine in Apple distributed cURL binary which breaks client certificate usage. Use the cURL binary from homebrew:

```
brew install curl
brew link curl --force
```

Comment: `brew link curl --force` no longer works, you must put `export "$(brew --prefix curl)/bin:$PATH"` in your .bash_profile instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was sending a wrong host header.

I was developing a proxy from http://127.0.0.1:12345 to https://site.com:443.
so I was sending request headers as-is as came from the browser and there was host:127.0.0.1:12345 header. I deleted the host header that came from browser to solve the problem.